# Windows Server Remote Desktop Services: Share Remote Desktop Session

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services

Is it possible to share a Remote Desktop Session between multiple (at least 2) users? I am searching for a solution that allows the users to use the native Remote Deskop Client. I am aware of the Remote Control feature but it only works if you are Administrator and is kind of "difficult to use" for my *stupid* users as it works only through the Remote Desktop Services Manager.

It is not a requirement that the login information for each user are different (e.g. if all share the same login that is fine for me).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real answer is to use remote control. A couple of your statements are wrong.

You do not need to be an administrator. There is a permission you can grant to non-administrators in order to allow them to request remote control. Go to Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration. Edit the properties of the RDP-Tcp connection. Goto the security tab and click on advanced. Add the user (or group) and allow them to remote control.

The second statement that you made is that you have to launch it from RDSM. This is not true either. It is much easier for users to launch it through Task Manager. Our non-technical accountant was setup to work with our outsourced accounting firm doing this. It works well and nobody has ever complained to me about it.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the access to which users a Remote Control can actually be made of a user that has such a right?

Comment: @Heinrich - Not that I know of. But it's been a while since I've set this up.

Comment: I've got a follow up question on this: http://serverfault.com/questions/340524/remote-desktop-session-remote-control-always-returns-error-5-access-denied