# Remote Desktop session remote control always returns Error 5: Access denied

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-terminal-services, remote-desktop-services

I am having problems to shadow the remote desktop session of a user on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

If I log on as local administrator on the server with RDP and shadow the session of a domain user that works. However, if I log on with a domain user that is in the local administrators group and try to shadow the session of the same user as I tried before, I get an error:

```
> shadow  ... 
Remote Control failed. error Code 5
Error [5]:Access is denied.
```

I explicitly enabled all permissions for the domain user which cannot shadow a session under:
Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration -> Rdp-Tcp connection -> Security -> checked Full Control

I even restarted the server after these modifications without success. I have exactly the same settings enabled on a different server and there a domain user, also being in the local administrators group can shadow sessions of other domain users.

So, are there any other settings I must enable to allow screensharing? Or do I do something wrong? Is there a way to determine which permissions an existing user actually has?

Comment: Does the user have a multi-display session?  The is a known bug.

Comment: No, no one uses multiple monitors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: The user must run the powershell with elevated rights. I used this solution for my script that starts a remote controlled session:

http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2009/07/26/get-content-access-to-the-path-cprogram-files-is-denied/